# What does the % size reference to in CSS table width?

Tags: html, css

What does the % size reference to for CSS table width? Is there a pixel size that it is reference to or is it relative to the table element? There seems to be no pattern when I adjust it in http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_width

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: In this particular example, the `width: 100%;` will be deduced from the parent element, `<body>`. Since `<body>` is not explicitly set it's `width` is set to auto, or the entire width of the document. If you were to change the width of the table to `width: 50%;` it would become half the width of the body (or document in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any percentage value in CSS always refers to the parent element. If your table is placed directly within the `<body>` element, a width of 100% refers to the entire width of the document. If the table is inside a wrapper, the 100% refers to the width of that wrapper.

Comment: thanks, but If the width of the wrapper or the parent element is not defined, what does it default to?

Comment: @user411754 The default width of an element is `auto`. The width itself is then computed based on several properties, like `display` and `margin`. This is very basic CSS knowledge. Please read a CSS tutorial, as those questions are answered out there on the web a million times.

Comment: @user411754 It depends on the layout of other components and page structure itself. All that can be inferred here is that the width of the table will be 100% the width of the wrapper.